# Monitor backup and restore in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I have a requirement to setup a process to monitor backup and restore in Marklogic. Which can send alert message or notification after failure of database backup and restore.

I find a function xdmp:database-backup-status which gives status of backup running in background. Didn't find a function which can tell us that last backup up has failed or success any time after the completion of the backup or restore.

Does any one have idea about tools or any logic that can help me to create such process

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[This knowledge base article](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/421/0/programmatically-finding-the-last-backup-date) walks through a couple ways to determine the last backup and last restore dates.

Both [`xdmp:database-backup-status`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:database-backup-status) and [`xdmp:database-restore-status`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:database-restore-status) should tell you if the backup or restore was completed successfully or not. Additionally, looking through the status information retrieved in the knowledge base article I linked to should also reveal that information as well.

Comment: Thanks Rob.. Is there any configuration that i can  use to trigger an action after completion backup or restore

Comment: @ArvindKr You could probably pull that off with a MarkLogic Scheduled Task.

Comment: @ArvindKr - Worth noting - xdmp:database-backup-status is ephemeral. If the host coordinating the backup restarts, it will not return information until the next backup is run.